# how to pass thymeleaf dropdown selected value to the spring boot controller

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

i want to pass thymeleaf dropdown selected value to the spring boot controller,using javascript or jquery or without that

```
<select id="cameraList" name="cameraListId" th:field="*{cameraid}" >
                   <option th:each="camera : ${camera}" th:value="${camera.cameraid}"
                           th:text="${camera.name}" th:selected="${camera.cameraid}">Camera</option>
               </select>
```

Comment: did you want to post the value when the user selects an option?

Comment: Yes Sean.Iwant to post the value

Answer (score 1):

This is my working solution

```
<div class="form-group"> 
        <select class="form-control" id="labelprofppayment"   name="paymentfield">
             <option th:value="'cash'" th:text="Cash"  th:selected="${profpayment == 'cash'}"></option>
            <option th:value="'transfer'" th:text="Transfer"  th:selected="${profpayment == 'transfer'}"></option>      
 </select></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller just create method to handle your request:

```
@Controller
YourController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/action", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String seach(@ModelAttribute Camera camera) {
        System.out.println("camera: " + camera);
        return "redirect_page";
    }
}
```

and in your view page, make a `form` with proper `action` and `method="post"` params.

Answer (score 0):

`${camera.cameraId}` in `th:selected` attribute will not pass the value to the controller.

`th:selected` is a boolean field and needs a condition. The condition depends on case to case but you can do something like this to start with:

```
th:selected="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the thymyleaf code and there is a dropdown I'm injecting data from the controller.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/expense/category}" th:object="${expense}"  method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Expense Name</label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Expense Description</label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{description}" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Description">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Amount</label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{amount}" class="form-control" id="amount" placeholder="Amount">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <label  class="col-form-label">Category </label>
                        <select  id="categorydropdown" name="categorydropdown" th:field="*{category.id}" >
                            <option th:each="category : ${categories}" th:value="${category.id}" th:utext="${category.name}"/>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Expense">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Below is the controller from which I'm injecting the data to the dropdown.

```
 @GetMapping("/addexpense")
    public String addExpense(Expense expense,Model model){
        model.addAttribute("categories",categoryRepo.findAll());
        return "addExpense";
    }
```

Below I have attached the controller to which i'm passing the data.(from form)

```
@PostMapping("/expense/category")
    public String createExpense( @RequestParam(name = "category.id") Long categoryid,@Valid  Expense expense, BindingResult result) {

         categoryRepo.findById(categoryid).map(expense1 -> {
            expense.setCategory(expense1);
            return expenseRepo.save(expense);
        });
         return "redirect:expenses";

    }
```